# Populate different title on different fullcalendar view

Tags: view, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar.io component to display data in calendar view. I have to use month/week/day view here. And I have to populate title on each even but that title would be different at different view. E.g. on month view title only my OrderId, but in week view title would be OrderId + location.

How can I populate different title on different view?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the EventAfterRender

```
eventAfterRender : function(event, element, view) {
    if (view.type == "month") {
        element.attr('title' , 'Your custom title');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for v6, try

```
eventDidMount: function(info) {

    if (info.view.type === "dayGridMonth") {
        info.event.setProp("title", "xxxx");
    } else {
      // .....
    }
}
```